# How do I associate my models for an escape room management rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to setup the associations with my models for a Rails app that would manage escape room games.

Basically, there are three models.

- Player
- Game Master
- Game

Players would request to play the game. Then the game master would approve each request before the game could start.

I'm assuming I associate my models like so, by using a **has_many :through association**

Here's an example of how I think the associations should be setup.

```
class GameMaster < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games
  has_many :players, through: :games
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game_master
  belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games
  has_many :game_masters, through: :games
end
```

Please let me know if I'm on the right path

Answer (score 0):

Because one Game can have multiple Players and one Player can have multiple Games, you will need a table association that combine game_id and player_id in one composite key.

In this way, a player can request for play in many games.

The same is needed for Game Master, If a game can have multiple Masters, that can approve request from players.

The PlayerGame will set the players of the game, and the MasterGame will set de masters of the game:

So you must have:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :player_games
  has_many :games, through: :player_games
end

class Master < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :master_games
  has_many :games, through: :master_games
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :player_games
  has_many :players, through: :player_games
  has_many :master_games
  has_many :masters, through: :master_games
end

class PlayerGame < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :game
end

class MasterGame < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :master
  belongs_to :game
end
```

It can be different if a user can be a master. Let me know. Suggestion, draw a entity relationship model to easy understand.